# Does PowerPivot work in SharePoint 2013 Foundation?

Tags: sql, sharepoint-2013, powerpivot

does PowerPivot and Excel Services work in SharePoint Foundation?  I am wondering how it works, and if you can even run the scheduling?

Also, does it require an instance of SQL Server Enterprise?

Bill.

Answer (score 0):

You asked more than one question, but I'll address the one in the question title.

> Does PowerPivot work in SharePoint 2013 Foundation?

According to this [feature comparision](http://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-2013/compare-sharepoint-foundation-server/), PowerPivot is **not** supported in SharePoint 2013 Foundation.  Nor is Excel Services (so that's two answers).